# Is there a regex statement to remove all print() statements from my Python/Django project?

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm preparing to go into production so want to remove all my print() statements before pushing my development code onto my server. Wondering if there is a clean way to do this.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Find replace returned about 2000 instances - as it included many packages and things like that. I also can't just replace the word `print` as there is an argument to account for, e.g. `print(comment.errors)` @JustinasMarozas Not yet because I want to make sure I have the best method and don't screw it up.

Comment: Install flake8-print

Comment: Most IDEs can search by regex. Try `print\(.*\)`. Shouldn't be more complicated than that.

Comment: this seems to be very opinion based. please add information about what you have tried, how it didnt (or did) work, and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Yep that works perfect @JustinasMarozas - thankyou.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas I'm finding alot of print statements in my installed packages, and even in Django's code...do I have to delete them aswell?

Comment: @Zorgan, it's best to leave third party packages alone. You'll modify them now, and when you'll update them or recreate your local environment you'll get surprises.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a unix-like operating system and want to do it by the command line try this:

```
cat filename.py | sed 's/\(^[[:space:]]*print([^)]*)\)/#\1/' > filename_without_comments.py
```

for each  file.

This `sed` command comments out lines with instances of `print(...)` .

The regex above is POSIX standard so should also work in the find and replace field of most text editors.